# sails.js custom route not working

Tags: node.js, routes, sails.js

This is a very simple sails.js project created from command line "sails new my-project". After having created the project, I create a controller, again, using the client tool (sails create controller dispatcher). In the api/controllers folder a new controller is generated ( DispatcherController.js). In this controller I have a simple method that returns a Hello World

```
function dispatch(req,res){
    res.send('hello world!');
}
```

Then I open the `config/routes.js` and enter a custom route

```
get /test: 'DispatcherController.dispatch'
```

I start my project. It runs at localhost:1337. Everything works fine. Now from my browser a enter the custom route url:

```
http://localhost:1337/test
```

But I am redirected to the default 404 page. Sails could resolve this route. I am completely lost here. How can someone create a custom route pointing to a controller and access it?

[see My routes.js file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8jVZWU6DPKeUzFTV2JzM3RScEU)

Comment: change log level to silly and start sails. check it there are no errors in router or it there are no policies attached to this route.

Comment: Thank for the answer. In the log I receive these messages:
Sending 404 ("Not Found") response
View override argument passed to res.view: 404
Serving view at rel path: 404
View root: F:\my-project\views

Comment: So I don't see any meaning full message. It just tells me that I am being redirected to the 404 page. Could it be that there are some restrictions on my local machine?

Comment: More important log is something like: Binding route ::  get /test (POLICY: sth) and any error after that.

Comment: I don't see an entry 'get /test'. I see:
Binding route :: /dispatcher/dispatch/:id? (POLICY: alwaysAllow)
; Binding route :: /dispatcher/dispatch/:id? (ACTION: dispatcher/dispatch)
...
some blueprint/shadow route for controller:dispatcher

but no 'get /test'

Comment: so you have some kind of error in your ```config/routes.js```. can you attach this file in question (just edit question)

Comment: @seyaobey Your entry in `routes.js` is in the format `'get /test':'DispatcherController.dispatch'` right? I see you have single quotes missing.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve the problem by having a closer look into my routes.js. The controller is DispatcherController.js and not DispatchController (as defined in the routes.js) After having corrected this typo it is working. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Your routes file has 'get /api' not 'get/test' try that first in your browser.

In your controller try 'return res.send...'

You can try a different send call too. 
'Res.json(200, {message: success});'

Answer (score 0):

in your controller

```
 dispatch: function(req,res){
         res.send('hello world!');
    }
```

in `routes` file

```
  "GET /test" : "DispatcherController.dispatch",
```